# Max--height in media queries Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, media-queries

In **[Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/)** I could use something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px), (max-height: 760px) {
}
```

and

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
}
```

How can I use the same feature in **[Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/)** syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Media-queries are a part of CSS, they have nothing to do with Bootstrap. As such,  it will work the same no matter what toolkit (if any) you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. **[Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)** are part of the **[CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)** **stylesheet language**. **[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)**, on the other hand, is just library built of top it with utility classes that make your job as a developer easier.

**EDIT** :

If you wish to migrate from **[Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/)** to **[Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/)**, take a look at the **[official migrating documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/)**